Sizing non-loadbearing header for 12 foot entry door
I recently completed renovations to an exterior load-bearing wall (with structural engineer approval) to accomodate a 8 foot by 12 foot sliding bifold door. The ceiling is 12 feet high; we brought the header supporting the roof up to 10 feet, so we'll need a non-loadbearing header to support the top track of the bifold door. I'm trying to determine what size lumber would be usable: I've received suggestions ranging from a 4x6 to an I-Beam. The door system is close to 1000 pounds, so while this header isn't bearing weight, I'd want to ensure that bowing isn't an issue.
The hangers for this beam are being secured to 4 x 12 LSLs, which support the built-up header that support the roof.

Your primary concern is lateral. Does the door have integrated structure, or is it dependent on attachment to the header for stability?

@isherwood There is no integrated structure in the door. When all the doors are open, there's about a 10 foot opening clear to the outside.

@isherwood I believe I misunderstood - I thought you meant integrated support in-between the door panels. The bottom and top frame contain channels that accomodates a roller and wheel system, and each panel is interlocked to one another using hinges. The sides of the frame are to be adhered to structural members; the manufacturer states that the top of the frame should be adhered to a structural member where possible, otherwise one should be provided.

"Adhered" is an odd word here, and I'm not sure what "otherwise" refers to after "where possible". Maybe link to or directly quote the instructions in your question post (not down here).
